# Сгенерировать данные и разложить в словарь с помощью python

Tags: python-3.x, dict

Пишу свою первую небольшую программу, которая предназначена для поиска информации по загрузке из архива рутрекера. Архив из себя представляет несколько папом с csv-файлами. В общих чертах все понятно, но с отдельной задачей я затупил.

Есть папка с csv-файлами. Среди них один файл со списком категорий:

"1";"Обсуждения, встречи, общение";"category_1.csv"

"2";"Кино, Видео и ТВ";"category_2.csv"

"4";"Новости";"category_4.csv"

"8";"Музыка";"category_8.csv"

"9";"Программы и Дизайн";"category_9.csv"

"10";"Обучающее видео";"category_10.csv"

"11";"Разное";"category_11.csv"

"18";"Сериалы";"category_18.csv"

"19";"Игры";"category_19.csv"

"20";"Документалистика и юмор";"category_20.csv"

"22";"Рок-музыка";"category_22.csv"

"23";"Электронная музыка";"category_23.csv"

"24";"Все по авто и мото";"category_24.csv"

"25";"Книги и журналы";"category_25.csv"

"26";"Apple";"category_26.csv"

"27";"Медицина и здоровье";"category_27.csv"

"28";"Спорт";"category_28.csv"

"29";"Мобильные устройства";"category_29.csv"

"31";"Джазовая и Блюзовая музыка";"category_31.csv"

"33";"Аудиокниги";"category_33.csv"

"34";"Обучение иностранным языкам";"category_34.csv"

"35";"Популярная музыка";"category_35.csv"

Из чего можно понять, что данные категорий могут быть разложены по одному, или нескольким файлам. Между категорией 2 и 4 пропущена цифра 3, что значит, что в файле "category_3.csv" лежат данные категории "Кино, Видео и ТВ", и т.д.

Хочу получить словарь, где каждой категории будет соответствовать имя файла, в котором лежат её данные. Или массив с именами файлов, если категория большая и лежит в нескольких файлах. В уме это решается на раз, а вот как объяснить машине я не понимаю.

Пользуясь этим словарем я планирую собрать другой, где будут разложены все категории, подкатегории, подподкатегории и другая информация. На мой взгляд это позволит сократить время поиска нужных данных. Линейный поиск я реализовал сразу же и его скорость на мой взгляд не приемлема.

Подскажите пожалуйста как решить данную задачу.

Comment: Если Вам подошёл ответ, [отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так, например:

(На самом деле вариант не очень красивый и не универсальный и мне не очень нравится, но рабочий)

(А ещё непонятно сколько файлов будет соответсвовать последней категории, только ли `category_35.csv` или ещё `category_36.csv` и т.д.)

```
in_str = '''
"1";"Обсуждения, встречи, общение";"category_1.csv"
"2";"Кино, Видео и ТВ";"category_2.csv"
"4";"Новости";"category_4.csv"
"8";"Музыка";"category_8.csv"
"9";"Программы и Дизайн";"category_9.csv"
"10";"Обучающее видео";"category_10.csv"
"11";"Разное";"category_11.csv"
"18";"Сериалы";"category_18.csv"
"19";"Игры";"category_19.csv"
"20";"Документалистика и юмор";"category_20.csv"
"22";"Рок-музыка";"category_22.csv"
"23";"Электронная музыка";"category_23.csv"
"24";"Все по авто и мото";"category_24.csv"
"25";"Книги и журналы";"category_25.csv"
"26";"Apple";"category_26.csv"
"27";"Медицина и здоровье";"category_27.csv"
"28";"Спорт";"category_28.csv"
"29";"Мобильные устройства";"category_29.csv"
"31";"Джазовая и Блюзовая музыка";"category_31.csv"
"33";"Аудиокниги";"category_33.csv"
"34";"Обучение иностранным языкам";"category_34.csv"
"35";"Популярная музыка";"category_35.csv"
''';

in_list = [[s.strip('"') for s in item.split(';')] for item in list(filter(lambda x: x != '', in_str.split('\n')))];
print(in_list, len(in_list), end = "\n\n");

output_dict = {};
for i in range(len(in_list)):
    n = 1;
    if ( i < len(in_list) - 1):
        n = int(in_list[i + 1][0]) - int(in_list[i][0]);
    output_dict[in_list[i][1]] = ["category_{}.csv".format(int(in_list[i][0]) + j) for j in range(n)];

print(output_dict);
```

Comment: Спасибо! Категории могут добавиться, но не уверен, что это будет скоро.